# MYSQL Update errors

Tags: mariadb

Getting errors on the following. seems simple, but can't clear this error:
NOTE: that wphz_posts.guid is a text field, not int
All table and column names are correct

> "SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ‘check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near ' WHERE wphz_postmeta.meta key = ‘ProductURL’ AND
> wphz_postmeta.post id = wphz.. at line 3

```
UPDATE wphz_posts 
SET wphz_posts.guid = (select concat(wphz_postmeta.meta_value,"?campid=nnnnnn")
WHERE wphz_postmeta.meta_key = 'ProductURL' AND wphz_postmeta.post_id = wphz_posts.id)
```

Comment: You can improved formatting by adding `\`\`\`` before and after code snippet. It's easier to understand and more pleasant to read for others

Comment: You have a `SELECT` statement without a `FROM` part, is that correct?

Comment: Last bracket should be before where?

Comment: You don't need a `SELECT CONCAT(...)`. Just `CONCAT(...)` will do.